# Why does Ruby hang when I use method_missing on String to redirect to chars?

Tags: ruby

When I implement this code:

```
class String

  def method_missing(meth,*args, &block)
    if self.chars.respond_to? meth
      self.chars.send meth, *args, &block
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to?(meth)
    if self.chars.respond_to? meth
      true
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

Ruby gets stuck on `flatten`.  Even requiring another file internally calls `flatten` so it hangs there.  I've even tried this:

```
class String

  def method_missing(meth,*args, &block)
    if meth.to_sym == :flatten
      super
    elsif self.chars.respond_to? meth
      self.chars.send meth, *args, &block
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def respond_to?(meth)
    if meth.to_sym == :flatten
      super
    elsif self.chars.respond_to? meth
      true
    else
      super
    end
  end

end
```

But the same results occur.  What's happening internally to cause `flatten` to fail?

Here's the error output:

```
2.1.2 :003 > require 'mygem'
 => true 
2.1.2 :004 > require 'pry'
^CIRB::Abort: abort then interrupt!
  from /home/user/dev/MyGem/lib/mygem/string_method_missing.rb:17:in `call'
  from /home/user/dev/MyGem/lib/mygem/string_method_missing.rb:17:in `respond_to?'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:112:in `flatten'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:112:in `initialize'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:70:in `new'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/requirement.rb:70:in `default'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:260:in `merge'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1323:in `block in activate_dependencies'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1306:in `each'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1306:in `activate_dependencies'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1288:in `activate'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems.rb:194:in `try_activate'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:132:in `rescue in require'
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
  from (irb):4
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

It happens strictly for any Array of strings which gets flattened.

```
2.1.2 :005 > [1,2,3].flatten
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.1.2 :006 > ["1","2","3"].flatten
^CIRB::Abort: abort then interrupt!
  from /home/user/dev/MyGem/lib/mygem/string_method_missing.rb:17:in `call'
  from /home/user/dev/MyGem/lib/mygem/string_method_missing.rb:17:in `respond_to?'
  from (irb):6:in `flatten'
  from (irb):6
  from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

**UPDATE**
I've updated the code for the fixes recommended in the comments.  The problem is still happening.  I'm looking forward to the answer.

Flatten seems to work if I tell it how deep to go.  So that seems to indicate an infinite loop on flattening the array on the string object.  Example:

```
2.1.2 :013 > ["1","2","3"].flatten(0)
 => ["1", "2", "3"] 
2.1.2 :021 > ["1","2","3"].flatten(8)
 => ["1", "2", "3"] 
2.1.2 :022 > ["1","2","3"].flatten(9)
 => ["1", "2", "3"]
```

How can I avoid the infinite loop and still do this method_missing?  It would help to know what test flatten calls on the inner object so I could define that in the string and avoid the loop.

Comment: What do you expect `meth.to_sym(*args, &block)` to do?

Comment: I vote to close due simple syntax error. You need `self.chars.send meth.to_sym, *args, &block` instead `self.chars.send meth.to_sym(*args, &block)`

Comment: @muistooshort It works by sending method calls on any string to the array version of the string as individual characters.  So I can do `"abcdef".values_at(2)` for example and it works.

Comment: But why are you sending all those arguments to `to_sym`? And why bother calling `to_sym` at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an inbuilt cap on flatten.  So redirecting everything to chars in String through method_missing creates an Array like object that will cause the flatten method to infinitely loop.

Add this, it is a working solution:

```
class Array
  # To fix a bug that our method_missing creates
  # we need to set a MAXIMUM for FLATTEN
  alias_method :_old_flatten, :flatten
  alias_method :_old_flatten!, :flatten!

  def flatten(level = 99)
    _old_flatten(level)
  end

  def flatten!(level = 99)
    _old_flatten!(level)
  end
end
```